# Grouper for 'x' not 1-dimensional in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datframe like the following photo(it's a sample of the complete database).

[image]

And i want to make a pandas pivot table to create something like this. (Excel example)

[image]

This is how i create the pivot table in excel.

[image]

And this is the python code

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['ANI'],columns=['Contact'],values=['ANI'],aggfunc='count')
```

And I'm getting the following mistake

```
ValueError : Grouper for 'ANI' not 1-dimensional
```

Based on what I was reading, it seems the problem is because im using the same series in 2 parameters, but actually that's how i need the pivot to be. Does someone knows a solution for this?

Comment: We can't copy/paste from pic, so provide the code please.

Answer (score 1):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ANI": [
            "332589",
            "368974",
            "879458",
            "875985",
            "879458",
            "368974",
            "879458",
            "368974",
            "879458",
            "368974",
            "879458",
            "332589",
            "875985",
        ],
        "Contact": [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df = (
    df
    .assign(Count=1)
    .groupby(["ANI", "Contact"])
    .agg(sum)
    .reset_index()
    .pipe(lambda df_: pd.pivot(df_, index="ANI", columns="Contact"))
    .fillna(0)
    .rename(columns={"Count": "Contact"})
)
df.columns.names = (None, None)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
       Contact     
             0    1
ANI
332589     0.0  2.0
368974     1.0  3.0
875985     0.0  2.0
879458     3.0  2.0
```

Comment: Awesome! Why did you `agg(sum)`? Isnt't `sum()` sufficient?

Comment: Thank you. `sum` is fine, indeed, just used to using `agg`. Cheers.